# Define Column Aliases?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT `*` 
  FROM (`threads` t, `members` m) 
 WHERE `m`.`id` = t.author 
   AND `t`.`type` = '0' 
   AND `t`.`category` = '1'
```

And basically what happens is that there is an ID field in both tables (members and threads) so what's happening is that the results array is getting messed up. IE: There is only one ID field which is being populated from the members table.

What I need to do is make the results with a prefix infront of their key name so I can distinguish between the two:
IE: Add 't.' to all thread fields and 'm.' to all members fields.

So results should be like: m.id = x, t.id = y
Instead, results at the moment are like: id = x (the id field from the thread table is completely overwritten by the one from the members table)

Comment: I know I could label them one by one but there are a bunch of fields and I was thinking there'd be a nicer way of doing like "SELECT m.* AS m.*, t.* AS t.*" which would create an alias for them all. Am I wrong in assuming this?

If this isn't possible, is there a way of storing the two tables into their own sub-arrays within the actual MySQL result array in such a way that it can all be done in one query still?

Comment: I always used to specify each column name. I do so mainly because I feel more secure, but I also know exactly what will be returned, even if I add fields. It's also easier to use, once you specified all field names. I've been googling around to see if there's a variable storing the actual field name, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT m.id AS x,
       t.id 'y' 
  FROM MEMBERS m
  JOIN THREADS t ON t.id = m.author
                AND t.type = '0'
                AND t.category = '1'
```

Column aliases are defined on a column by column basis - you can't use wildcards/etc.
You can use the `AS` keyword, or simply enclose the column alias within single quotes *if* the column name doesn't contain special characters - use double quotes if it does.  You can combine single/double quote usage with the `AS` keyword.

### Do I have to List all the Columns?

---

Yes, you have to list all the columns unless you like duplicate columns because you choose to use `m.*` or `t.*`.   There is no convention in SQL that supports what you ask. `SELECT *` [is not an ideal practice - read this answer for details beyond this situation why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128625/i-was-taught-that-select-from-table-is-bad-is-it-still-true/2128704#2128704).

### Addendum

---

I took the liberty of rewriting your query to use ANSI-92 JOIN syntax - your example used ANSI-89.  There's no performance difference.

Comment: I forgot to mention that backticks are only necessary in MySQL queries if database, table and/or column names turn out to be MySQL keywords: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: I still need to return the other fields as well, so is there a way to do that without returning the ID fields again but without having to list out each field?

Comment: @NJ: No, you will need to list each column.  See this answer for why `SELECT *` isn't ideal for things besides this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128625/i-was-taught-that-select-from-table-is-bad-is-it-still-true/2128704#2128704

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by naming each column one by one:

```
SELECT m.`id` AS "m_id", `t`.`id` AS "t_id", t.`username` AS "t_username"
FROM (`threads` t, `members` m) 
WHERE `m`.`id` = t.author 
   AND `t`.`type` = '0' 
   AND `t`.`category` = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an alias for columns that have the same name:

```
SELECT t.ID as threadsID, m.ID as membersID, <...> WHERE `m`.`id` = t.author AND `t`.`type` = '0' AND `t`.`category` = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the id's to be separate, you can do

```
SELECT `*`, t.id as t_id, m.id as m_id
  FROM (`threads` t, `members` m) 
WHERE `m`.`id` = t.author 
  AND `t`.`type` = '0' 
  AND `t`.`category` = '1'
```

As the others said, it's a column alias.